# Are Web-to-Leads tracked as Event Logs?

Tags: logging, web-to-case

**Background**

I’m using Salesforce Event Logs to Monitor my Salesforce instance.

**Question**

Is Web-To-Lead tracked as part of Salesforce Event Logs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. There are about 50 Supported Event Types that you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm), and w2l are not explicitly called out.

Since W2L records are created by the Default Lead Owner, you can set the log on for that user and get some data. Also, if you use encryption,  you can encrypt custom fields using the Platform Encryption. To read up more, here is the [implementation guide](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_platform_encryption_implementation_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There are 48 Event Types which can be monitored from EventLog.

Here are they, but Web-to-Lead is not tracked under this.

[Event types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm)

Comment: Hmm - I wonder if it is tracked under the URI event type as it is a basically a  form POST; we have event monitoring in our org but not W2L so hard for me to check